# Alternative to glRotatef and glutBitmapCharacter?

Tags: opengl, 2d, glut

This is what my code is currently. However, for the life of me I cannot get the text to rotate. Do I need to use something other than glutBitmapCharacter?

Just to clarify, this is only a 2D program

main.cpp

```
#include "bookshelf.h"

void Initialize()
{
    glClearColor (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0 );
    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0,799,799,0,0.0,1.0);
}
void main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{    
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB );
    glutInitWindowSize( 800, 800 );
    glutInitWindowPosition( 200, 50 );
    glutCreateWindow("Bookshelf - Ankit Ahuja");
    Initialize();
    glutDisplayFunc(Bookshelf);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

bookshelf.h

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

void Bookshelf()
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();

    glColor3f( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
    glRasterPos2f(170,90);
    glRotatef(0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
    char text1[50]="Apple Recipe Book";
    for(int i=0; i<50; i++) glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_8_BY_13,text1[i]);
    glRasterPos2f(190,110);
    glRotatef(0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
    char text2[50]="Banana Recipe Book";
    for(int i=0; i<50; i++) glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_8_BY_13,text2[i]);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep.

glutBitmapCharacter() is just going to splat a char on the screen (note the call to glRasterPos2f()).

There's no built-in support for 3D fonts in OpenGL, but a lot of 3rd party APIs. See this link for a summary:[OpenGL Fonts](http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/features/fontsurvey/)

I don't like just pasting in a link, but I do use the FreeType2 library listed, and I've had good success with it.

Comment: oh, so this would only be possible with 3d fonts? opengl has nothing in 2d that can rotate?

Comment: @AnkitAhuja: Well, you can use texture mapped fonts and those will be transformed. But the raster operations (glDrawPixels, glBitmap and so on), they are always aligned to the pixel grid. And transformations are only applied to the starting position of the raster pos. Truth to be told, I'd not bother using them, (except glReadPixels). All the drawing raster operations are slow, poorly maintained and have actually been removed from later versions of OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

Give [`glutStrokeCharacter()`](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node78.html#SECTION000113000000000000000) a shot.

Or use `glutBitmapCharacter()` and your choice of render-to-texture method.  Then render a quad with your texture in whatever orientation you want.